# Windows App can't access service from some networks but browser can

Tags: windows, cordova, networking

I have a Windows App built with Cordova which has trouble accessing it's web service from **some** networks.

I don't believe this is a CORS problem.  The application works, especially from public networks but when the user switches to an inside network, either by direct connect or VPN, the application fails to connect.  By inside I mean inside the organization which is hosting the Web Service.

If I debug the application the error is:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.
```

- If I ask the user to open a browser to the service URL it always
  works.
- The service is not being called via HTTPS so there is no
  problem with SSL certificates.
- The app is running on both Windows 8 and Windows 10 tablets.

I am pretty sure there is network layer issue of some kind but I don't know what to look for.

I saw the following answer to a related question:

> ...I recommend that you collect a Network trace using a
>   tool such as Microsoft Network Monitor or Wireshark to understand what
>   IP Address is the connection being made to. The 0x2efd error
>   correlates to the WinINet error: ERROR_INTERNET_CANNOT_CONNECT meaning
>   that the connection with the remote server cannot be established. When
>   you collect a network trace, try looking for the TCP-SYN signal and
>   see whether your remote server responds with a SYN-ACK.
>
> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7cba42bc-0a93-4199-b767-d6e611c0e4d6/error-script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2efd-could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to?forum=winappswithhtml5

My problem is that I am very remote from the problem and as much as I would like it I can't just hop over to Hawaii from Canada.

I am looking for any advice on how trouble shoot this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The networking problems with the Mobile app ended up being a result of an application settings that was used to build the application.

The settings are described in this article.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/apps/br211423.aspx

The settings in the application were initially set at “internetClient”.    We needed to **add** “privateNetworkClientServer”.   I specifically said **add** because setting it to privateNetworkClientServer just changed the problem.  As a result that section of the application manifest now looks as follows.

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
</Capabilities>
```

We made the change to all [*.appxmanifest] files found in the [app\cordova\platforms\windows] folder.

Comment: I would also like to point out this defect: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12628 , which may affect many people trying to implement this fix through their config.xml.  There is also a plugin you can install that will fix this: https://github.com/dilhan2013/cordova-windows-capability-localnetwork